# What's the difference between "names" and "chunks" in CommonsChunkPlugin?

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, commonschunkplugin

What's the difference between those two fields in plugins options?

How are they related to each other?
Which one is executed first, which one second?
How can I pick a package from a chunk info a separate file with these options?

```
  name: string, // or
  names: string[],
  chunks: string[],
```

What does highlighted text below mean for `chunks: string[]` option? How to read `child` in that context?

> // Select the source chunks by chunk names. **The chunk must be a
>   child of the commons chunk.**   // If omitted all entry chunks are
>   selected.

Webpack and particularly its splitting features is something that is very unfriendly, rather difficult to understand and use.